# Java Security RSA - InvalidKeyException

Tags: java, encryption, runtime-error, rsa

I am currently working on a tool for asymmetric encryption with RSA:

```
PublicKey FrKey;

public byte[] encrypt(String msg) {

    byte[] msg1 = null;

    Cipher cp = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    cp.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, FrKey);
    msg1 = cp.doFinal(msg.getBytes());

    return msg1;
}

public void setOpKey(String s) {

        X509EncodedKeySpec pubKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(s.getBytes()));
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(pubKeySpec);
        System.out.println("Friends Public: "+s+"\n\n"+publicKey);
}
```

While the setOpKey function, which is supposed to set the opponents Public Key, seems to work just fine, when the encryption class is run java returns an error:

> java.security.InvalidKeyException: No installed provider supports this key: (null)

From this Error you would read, that the Key would be null, but as seen in the console output below it isn't.

> Friends Public: */String I entered, generated from the RSA*/
>
> Sun RSA public key, 1024 bits
>
> modulus: */Very long number*/
>
> public exponent: 65537

This seems to be an error with the Public Key, but I have no clue how that could be fixed. Any help would be appreciated.

PS: I removed all try/catch clauses to make the code more readable.

Comment: You are not assigning the public key value loaded into `setOpKey` to `FrKey`, so it is probably null.

Comment: I am an Idiot, thanks :)